# Sending message to Azure IoT Hub via python HTTPS - using urllib3 - results in no response

Tags: python, azure, python-2.7, rest, azure-iot-hub

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/send-device-event) and also according to several online posts, the response when you send a message to an Azure IoT Hub device successfully is: "204 No Content".

We know the message is sent successfully and received by IoTHub and we can see the message (including message body): 1) in Device Explorer tool, 2) we can see it by using the Azure IoT SDK (azure.eventhub) and creating a read function and 3) we can also see the messages in the Azure Portal.

We do get a 204 response when sending a message using the Python **request library** in Python 3.8.  However, for one location we need to use the Python **urllib3 library** and we are getting NO response at all doing a POST.  The code is below.
Note: we tried urllib2 earlier and we also got no response.

1. What is the data type of the usual successful response from Azure IoT Hub?  Is it a simple string?
2. What could be preventing the response from showing up in urllib3 and also urllib2?

Thanks.
GH

```
import urllib3
import json
import datetime
import ssl
import certifi

print("certifi: " + certifi.where())
print("urllib3 ver: " + urllib3.__version__)
print("ssl ver: " + ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

# IoT DeviceID
deviceID = "gwy1"
# Iot Hub Name
IoTHubName = "aziothub1"
# RestAPI Version
iotHubAPIVer = "2020-03-13"
iotHubRestURI = "https://" + IoTHubName + ".azure-devices.net/devices/" + deviceID + "/messages/events?api-version=" + iotHubAPIVer

SASToken = "SharedAccessSignature sr=gwy1-aziothub1.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fglualwpr-gwy1&sig=v-----------------------------------&se=1629182336"


# Message Payload
datetime =  datetime.datetime.now()
body = {}
body['datetime'] = str(datetime)
body['deviceClient'] = deviceID
body['Message'] = 'Python Device to Cloud Message over HTTPS'

encoded_body = json.dumps(body)

# Headers
Headers = {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : SASToken
}


http = urllib3.PoolManager(ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

httpResponse =  http.request('POST', iotHubRestURI,
                headers=Headers,
                body=encoded_body)

print ("response: " + httpResponse.read()) # Do something with the response
```

Comment: What is the status code you are getting with `urllib3`?

Comment: In urllib3 we are getting an Empty response (blank).  Earlier we tried urllib2 but since there was no response (empty response) we tried urrlib3.  However, urllib3 is the same.  Thanks.

Comment: I mean what is `httpResponse.status` code?

Comment: Thanks Abdul Niyas, your comment led to finding the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using urllib3 Python library: to get the status code (which is an Integer) one must get the value of the field status.  The function read() does NOT return anything.

This line works:

```
print ("Response status: " + str(httpResponse.status))
```